# Sending a form with a jQuery file by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My goal is to create a form to send an image to the server through Ajax via jQuery.

I already asked the question here ([Problem sending a form with a jquery file component by ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734956/problem-sending-a-form-with-a-jquery-file-component-by-ajax)), but it's been closed and it still doesn't work. From my question, I changed the sending function like this (according to this post: [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)):

```js
$( "#sendProfileImg").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var file_data = $('#profileImgFile').prop('files')[0];   
  var form_data = new FormData();                  
  form_data.append('file', file_data);
  console.log(form_data); 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'uploadImage.php',
    data: form_data,
    type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'text',
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          processData:false,
    success: function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

But the answer I get from my uploadImage.php file (which consist of just var_dump($_POST);) is the following:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Please share the php code.

Comment: what does `console.log(form_data); ` result in?

Answer (score -1):

Since your request only has the file you might want want to use the `$_FILES` variable instead of `$_POST`. Uploaded files can only accessed through the `$_FILES` variable.

Answer (score -1):

three things

- use $_FILES instead $_POST please check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) url
- check if you have an updated browser(not all browsers are compatible with FormData)
  check the browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: whoever you are that downvote the question please tell why is that, I know that the question is incomplete but not for that my answer is invalid and deserve a downvote

Comment: Your answer can be improved to include some explanations instead of just things to do.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much everbody, the problem is solved.

I discovered 2 issues:

1. I have to use *form_data.append*. I didn't know this function and it wasn't on the tutorials I followed. Furthermore, I had to use this funtion for every field of the formular, not just the one with the file
2. $_POST return no information about the posted files. That's why I didn't get any return about the posted information.

Thanks again everybody